# Deep learning Udacity course: Prob 2 assignment 1 (notMNIST)

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

After reading [this](https://discussions.udacity.com/t/assingment-1-1-notmnist-ipynb-well-convert-the-entire-dataset-into-a-3d-array-image-index-x-y-of-floating-point-values-normalized-to-have-approximately-zero-mean-and-standard-deviation-0-5-to-make-training-easier-down-the-road/45902) and taking the courses, I am struggling to solve the second problem in assignment 1 ([notMnist](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud730/l-6370362152/m-6370314231)):

> Let's verify that the data still looks good. Displaying a sample of the labels and images from the ndarray. Hint: you can use matplotlib.pyplot.

Here is what I tried:

```
import random
rand_smpl = [ train_datasets[i] for i in sorted(random.sample(xrange(len(train_datasets)), 1)) ]
print(rand_smpl)
filename = rand_smpl[0]
import pickle
loaded_pickle = pickle.load( open( filename, "r" ) )
image_size = 28  # Pixel width and height.
import numpy as np
dataset = np.ndarray(shape=(len(loaded_pickle), image_size, image_size),
                         dtype=np.float32)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(dataset[2])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

but this is what I get:

[image]

which doesn't make much sense. To be honest my code may too, since I am not really sure how to tackle that problem!

---

The pickles are created like this:

```
image_size = 28  # Pixel width and height.
pixel_depth = 255.0  # Number of levels per pixel.

def load_letter(folder, min_num_images):
  """Load the data for a single letter label."""
  image_files = os.listdir(folder)
  dataset = np.ndarray(shape=(len(image_files), image_size, image_size),
                         dtype=np.float32)
  print(folder)
  num_images = 0
  for image in image_files:
    image_file = os.path.join(folder, image)
    try:
      image_data = (ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float) - 
                    pixel_depth / 2) / pixel_depth
      if image_data.shape != (image_size, image_size):
        raise Exception('Unexpected image shape: %s' % str(image_data.shape))
      dataset[num_images, :, :] = image_data
      num_images = num_images + 1
    except IOError as e:
      print('Could not read:', image_file, ':', e, '- it\'s ok, skipping.')
    
  dataset = dataset[0:num_images, :, :]
  if num_images < min_num_images:
    raise Exception('Many fewer images than expected: %d < %d' %
                    (num_images, min_num_images))
    
  print('Full dataset tensor:', dataset.shape)
  print('Mean:', np.mean(dataset))
  print('Standard deviation:', np.std(dataset))
  return dataset
```

where that function is called like this:

```
  dataset = load_letter(folder, min_num_images_per_class)
  try:
    with open(set_filename, 'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump(dataset, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

The idea here is:

> Now let's load the data in a more manageable format. Since, depending on your computer setup you might not be able to fit it all in memory, we'll load each class into a separate dataset, store them on disk and curate them independently. Later we'll merge them into a single dataset of manageable size.
>
> We'll convert the entire dataset into a 3D array (image index, x, y) of floating point values, normalized to have approximately zero mean and standard deviation ~0.5 to make training easier down the road.

Comment: We cannot look at your link unless we're registered for the course. Please paste relevant discussion in your question.

Comment: @erip thanks for your comment. Is that [link](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud730/l-6370362152/m-6370314231) accessible? Hmm, you are right.

Comment: Yes, the commented link is accessible.

Comment: OK great @erip! I also edited the code to be minimal. That extra code was leftovers from the first problem that I solved (which I can post if it helps).

Comment: I think your big problem is that all you've done is declared `dataset` (and not initialized it). It was loaded with junk values (in this case, 0's). You're not plotting anything. Without more data or context, I am not sure there's much we can do.

Comment: Shouldn't the dataset be initialized here: `dataset = np.ndarray(shape=(len(loaded_pickle), image_size, image_size),
                         dtype=np.float32)`? I updated my post with more info. Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: Because `numpy` uses C under the hood, that declares a 3D array, but it doesn't initialize it. See [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this as below:

```
#define a function to conver label to letter
def letter(i):
    return 'abcdefghij'[i]


# you need a matplotlib inline to be able to show images in python notebook
%matplotlib inline
#some random number in range 0 - length of dataset
sample_idx = np.random.randint(0, len(train_dataset))
#now we show it
plt.imshow(train_dataset[sample_idx])
plt.title("Char " + letter(train_labels[sample_idx]))
```

Your code changed the type of dataset actually, it is not an ndarray of size (220000, 28,28)

In general, pickle is a file which holds some objects, not the array itself. You should use the object from pickle directly to get your train dataset (using the notation from your code snippet):

```
#will give you train_dataset and labels
train_dataset = loaded_pickle['train_dataset']
train_labels = loaded_pickle['train_labels']
```

UPDATED:

Per request from @gsarmas the link to my solution for whole Assignment1 lies [here](https://github.com/MaxKHK/Udacity_DeepLearningAssignments/blob/master/Assignment1/1_notmnist.ipynb).

The code is commented and mostly self-explanatory, but in case of any questions feel free to contact via any way you prefer on github

Comment: Also if you want I could give you link to my notebook with solutions to this whole assignment so that you can use it as example

Comment: Oh I see, so my code was not too awful, it was just awful! Yes Maxim, that would be great, so that I can use it to get unstuck whenever I have problems.

Comment: @gsamaras will post it to git in several hours and add it here.

Comment: Maxim you do not know how helpful this will be! I will post an error, but if you are not sure why I am getting that, just let me do the research on the link you will share to solve!I am trying to get the problem working, but I am getting a warning `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:19: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future` and then an error in the train_dataset: `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: @gsamaras I suspect the warning comes from rand_smpl generation. You use random.sample function and from its documentation (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.sample.html#numpy.random.sample) you could see it gives back floats, not integers. Hence the indexing is wrong.

Comment: @gsamaras per your request, updated answer to include link to my solution

Comment: Thanks Maxim, I am trying so hard to take a random sample with your code, but I fail, because `letter_set` is a `numpy.ndarray`. Any idea? In your code (I mean in the link you kindly shared with us) you access the first one.

Comment: @gsamaras can you tell me how you use it? I just ran this notebook from first to last line and got no errors (I reloaded it on git a sec ago to include results and a bit of adjustments)? At which exact moment you get the error?

Comment: Maxim sorry for my misplacement of the question. I get no errors. In Problem 2, we show an image; in your code you do `plt.imshow(letter_set[0])`. However, I am trying to print a random image, not the first one, but I just cannot find a way to pick one at random. Do you know any?

Comment: @gsarmas in my code you could find how I randomly sample an images down the road. I have updated answer to show random letter imageshow, check it

Comment: Maxim I did it a bit different, but yes everything works nicely. Off I go to the 2nd assignment! :D I owe it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with this code

```
pickle_file = train_datasets[0]
with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as f:

# unpickle
letter_set = pickle.load(f)  

# pick a random image index
sample_idx = np.random.randint(len(letter_set))

# extract a 2D slice
sample_image = letter_set[sample_idx, :, :]  
plt.figure()

# display it
plt.imshow(sample_image)
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
#random select a letter
i = np.random.randint( len(train_datasets) )
plt.title( "abcdefghij"[i] )

#read the file of selected letter
f = open( train_datasets[i], "rb" )
f = pickle.load(f)

#random select an image in the file
j = np.random.randint( len(f) )

#show image
plt.axis('off')
img = plt.imshow( f[ j, :, : ] )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdpQP.png)

Comment: Oh, f[j] get the same result. Cool!